# C++ lambda passed to Obj-C contains nil references when called

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++

How can a C++ object be set as a delegate for an Objective-C protocol?

I attempted to have the Obj-C interface take blocks instead. When setting the block variable from the C++ class it works and the callback occurs. The C++ object references inside the block are all nil though.

The block gets called from Obj-C code but when breakpointing inside the block that was set in the C++ code, everything is nil, resulting in a crash of bad access.

I could create a reference to the C++ object in the Obj-C class and call it directly, but I would like to decouple the Obj-C object.

What is the reason for the blocks having nil values?

Comment: Post a short code example, this is not enough to go by.

Comment: Does the lambda capture any data by reference?  Perhaps it's invalid by the time it gets called?  Without code nobody can do more than blindly guess.